# Matlab program that writes y'(x)^2 as output for differential equation

Tags: matlab, differential-equations

I am working on a second degree non-linear ODE problem, and I have to find the expression of y'(x)^2.
I want to check the result I got using Matlab.
Please could you help me ?

Comment: So you have an energy equation like `E = y'(x)^2+V(y(x))` and want to compute the symbolic derivative `0=y'(x)*(y''(x)+V'(y(x)))` of it?

Comment: Well.. It's the penduluum Differential equation :

Comment: Please write the equations, or maybe add your code so that we can see more clearly what you mean.